# using phpexcel set cell data to posted form data

Tags: php, webforms, phpexcel

Hi looking to set the cell data in generated excel spreadsheet to what the user has inputted in the web form how would i call the form data?

here is the piece of code used to write the excel spreadsheet:

```
    // Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');
```

Comment: uses more details please. otherwise resolved with a simple `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the string values like `'Hello'` and `'world!'` with the data from your html form

```
objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', $_POST['form_field_name']);
```